# Accessing my localhost through phone results in errors loading resources

Tags: windows-7, android, localhost

I want to browse through my PC's localhost using my android phone. I need it, because I want to test my websites on mobiles without uploading entire project on my server. Is it possible? For now, I enter `192.168.1.4`, which is my PC's address and it works, but partially only. Problem is, it doesn't load any images, css nor js files. What can I do? I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: How are you referencing your CSS/JS files in your HTML code?

Comment: It's WordPress, so by `http://localhost/...`. I guess that's the problem.

Comment: Yeah, that would be a problem. Just leave the `http://localhost` part, so that the URL becomes relative. Then it should work.

Comment: This question at [android.se] might have some useful information: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26692/connect-to-laptops-localhost-websites

Answer (score 0):

I changed my site address (at WordPress' config) from `localhost` to `192.168.1.4` and it works well :)